# Threading for iframe elements in IE

Tags: javascript, multithreading, iframe, internet-explorer

Of the following, which are not run in the same thread as the current page in **IE8**?

- An iframe with the same domain as the current page.
- An iframe with a sub-domain of the current page's domain.
- An iframe with a super-domain of the current page's domain.
- An iframe with a completely different domain from the current page.

I want to know this for implementing [Web Workers](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/) in IE that are in separate threads.

**Edit**: Is there *any* way to have a `window` in another thread in IE to `postMessage` to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IE threading is not tied to the domain of the resource. An iframe DOM is build and is tied to the same thread as the main browser document.

Comment: So it's impossible to postMessage a window in a separate thread in IE?

Comment: It's possible. However, you have to start the thread somehow yourself, which can't be done from JS.

Answer (score 2):

As Franci mentioned, using an iframe will not get you a new thread. However, you can "simulate" multi-threading with setTimeout and callbacks:

- "Multi-threading in JavaScript": http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/multi-threading-javascript
- The fakeworker.js (An implementation of Web Workers using this setTimeout trick): http://code.google.com/p/fakeworker-js/